# Can a new Android project required to support from Android 4.2 up to Android 10 use AndroidX?

Tags: android, androidx

I am a new Android developer.

I have a new Android project (for industrial use) that requires to support from Android 4.2 to Android 10 (this is a hard requirement.)

I downloaded IntelliJ, created a new Android project, and found that it defaults to use Androidx.

When I clicked "run" and chose API level 17 (Android 4.2), the code can be run in the emulator. As far as I know, Androidx is something after API level 28 (Android 9.0), my question is can Apps based on Androidx run without any potential issues in Android 4.2 (real phone)?

For this new project, shall I maintain two versions, one using supporting library (for old version of Android), and one using Androidx? Or one version that uses Androidx should be enough?

Thanks.

Comment: AndroidX _is_ the (modern) support library. It's exactly what you want for projects that need to run on older APIs.

Comment: The older support library which AndroidX supersedes has minSDK of 14, from: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library#api-versions but as always test given that fewer people are using older devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary.AndroidX contains supporting library.